# Get input by id/name of textbox knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a input textarea as below :

```
<textarea data-bind="value: $data.text, attr: { name: 'Data[' + $index() + '].Text', id: 'Data[' + $index() + '].Input'}" name="Data[1].Text" id="Data[1].Text"></textarea>
```

On button click I want to grab the id of the textarea in which data is entered. The  click event is in the knockoutJS code. Also there can be multiple textarea .

How can I get the id in knockout js code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a list (since there could be multiple textareas). You can use the click binding on the button and get all the textareas using jQuery.

```
<p>Text area 1 <textarea id="login" data-bind="value: userName" ></textarea></p>
<p>Text area 2 <textarea  id="pwd"  type="password" data-bind="value: userPassword" ></textarea></p>

<button data-bind="click: getIdList"> click me </button>

<script>
    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        this.userName = ko.observable("");    
        this.userPassword = ko.observable(""); 
        this.getIdList = function() {
            var textAreaList = $("textarea");
            var idList = "";
            textAreaList.each(function( key, element ) {
                if(element.value !== "")
                    idList += element.getAttribute("id") + ",";
            });
            return idList.slice(0, -1);
        };
    }
    var myViewModel = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
</script>
```